# Can I get alert when eureka client health is DOWN?

Tags: alert, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I know Eureka can check service health.

I want to know How I get alert(email, slack) when eureka client service status is "DOWN"?

I check eureka client health every 5 minutes.

Comment: Not without some effort. There's no such integration. Eureka isn't a monitoring service.

Comment: Yes you can, you may check [spring-boot-admin documentation](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/blob/master/spring-boot-admin-docs/src/main/asciidoc/server-notifications.adoc)